# Linq to SQL Query Slow

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do the following SQL query with linq to sql.

```
select  COURSE_SECTIONS.SEC_SUBJECT,
        COURSE_SECTIONS.SEC_COURSE_NO,
        COURSE_SECTIONS.SEC_NO,
        SectionEnrollments.SectionEnrollment
from    COURSE_SECTIONS
        inner join  (select STC_COURSE_NAME, STC_SECTION_NO, COUNT(*) AS SectionEnrollment
        from        STUDENT_ACAD_CRED
        where       STC_TERM = '2012FL'
        group       by STC_COURSE_NAME, STC_SECTION_NO) as SectionEnrollments
                    on COURSE_SECTIONS.SEC_SUBJECT + '-' + COURSE_SECTIONS.SEC_COURSE_NO = SectionEnrollments.STC_COURSE_NAME
                       and COURSE_SECTIONS.SEC_NO = SectionEnrollments.STC_SECTION_NO
where   SEC_TERM = '2012FL'
```

My first attempt is this

```
var query = from sections in db.COURSE_SECTIONS
    where sections.SEC_TERM == "2012FL"
    orderby sections.SEC_SUBJECT, sections.SEC_COURSE_NO, sections.SEC_NO
    select 
        new 
        { 
            sections.SEC_SUBJECT, 
            sections.SEC_COURSE_NO, 
            sections.SEC_NO,
            sectionEnrollmentCount = (from enrollments in db.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED
                where enrollments.STC_TERM == "2012FL"
                group enrollments by
                    new
                    {
                        STC_COURSE_NAME = enrollments.STC_COURSE_NAME,
                        STC_SECTION_NO = enrollments.STC_SECTION_NO
                    } into grouping
                where grouping.Key.STC_COURSE_NAME == sections.SEC_SUBJECT + "-" + sections.SEC_COURSE_NO
                    && grouping.Key.STC_SECTION_NO == sections.SEC_NO
                select grouping.Count()).FirstOrDefault()
        };
```

This actual works but takes nearly 30 to return the results (about 900 records).  The SQL takes under a second.

This is my next attempt to try to get it to run faster.

```
var query2 = from sections in db.COURSE_SECTIONS
    join groupingQuery in 
        (from enrollments in db.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED
        where enrollments.STC_TERM == "2012FL"
        group enrollments by
            new
            {
                STC_COURSE_NAME = enrollments.STC_COURSE_NAME,
                STC_SECTION_NO = enrollments.STC_SECTION_NO
            } into grouping
        select new { grouping.Key, EnrollmentCount = grouping.Count() } )
        on sections.SEC_SUBJECT + "-" + sections.SEC_COURSE_NO + "-" + sections.SEC_NO equals groupingQuery.Key.STC_COURSE_NAME + "-" + groupingQuery.Key.STC_SECTION_NO
        into sectionEnrollmentCount
    where sections.SEC_TERM == "2012FL"
    orderby sections.SEC_SUBJECT, sections.SEC_COURSE_NO, sections.SEC_NO
    select
        new
        {
            sections.SEC_SUBJECT,
            sections.SEC_COURSE_NO,
            sections.SEC_NO,
        sectionEnrollmentCount
        };
```

However, for the sectionEnrollmentCount variable type is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String],System.Int32]] and I can't figure out how to get it to become a number.

Can someone help me to get this to work?

Thanks,

EDIT

This is the SQL that the first attempt is generating.

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[SEC_SUBJECT] AS [SEC_SUBJECT], 
[Project1].[SEC_COURSE_NO] AS [SEC_COURSE_NO], 
[Project1].[SEC_NO] AS [SEC_NO], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
[Filter1].[SEC_SUBJECT] AS [SEC_SUBJECT], 
[Filter1].[SEC_COURSE_NO] AS [SEC_COURSE_NO], 
[Filter1].[SEC_NO] AS [SEC_NO], 
1 AS [C1], 
CASE WHEN ([Limit1].[A1] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Limit2].[A1] END AS [C2]
FROM    (SELECT [Extent1].[SEC_SUBJECT] AS [SEC_SUBJECT], [Extent1].[SEC_COURSE_NO] AS [SEC_COURSE_NO], [Extent1].[SEC_NO] AS [SEC_NO]
    FROM [dbo].[COURSE_SECTIONS] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE '2012FL' = [Extent1].[SEC_TERM] ) AS [Filter1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[STC_COURSE_NAME] AS [K1], 
        [Extent2].[STC_SECTION_NO] AS [K2], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[STUDENT_ACAD_CRED] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE '2012FL' = [Extent2].[STC_TERM]
        GROUP BY [Extent2].[STC_COURSE_NAME], [Extent2].[STC_SECTION_NO]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
    WHERE ([GroupBy1].[K1] = ([Filter1].[SEC_SUBJECT] + N'-' + [Filter1].[SEC_COURSE_NO])) AND ([GroupBy1].[K2] = [Filter1].[SEC_NO]) ) AS [Limit1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent3].[STC_COURSE_NAME] AS [K1], 
        [Extent3].[STC_SECTION_NO] AS [K2], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[STUDENT_ACAD_CRED] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE '2012FL' = [Extent3].[STC_TERM]
        GROUP BY [Extent3].[STC_COURSE_NAME], [Extent3].[STC_SECTION_NO]
    )  AS [GroupBy2]
    WHERE ([GroupBy2].[K1] = ([Filter1].[SEC_SUBJECT] + N'-' + [Filter1].[SEC_COURSE_NO])) AND ([GroupBy2].[K2] = [Filter1].[SEC_NO]) ) AS [Limit2]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[SEC_SUBJECT] ASC, [Project1].[SEC_COURSE_NO] ASC, [Project1].[SEC_NO] ASC
```

This is the linq-to-sql command that works

```
from section in db.COURSE_SECTIONS
join SectionEnrollments in (
    (from  STUDENT_ACAD_CRED in db.STUDENT_ACAD_CRED
        where STUDENT_ACAD_CRED.STC_TERM == "2012FL"
        group STUDENT_ACAD_CRED by new {
            STUDENT_ACAD_CRED.STC_COURSE_NAME,
            STUDENT_ACAD_CRED.STC_SECTION_NO } into g
        select new {
        g.Key.STC_COURSE_NAME,
        g.Key.STC_SECTION_NO,
        SectionEnrollment = (Int64?)g.Count()
    }))
        on section.SEC_SUBJECT + "-" + section.SEC_COURSE_NO + "-" + section.SEC_NO
            equals SectionEnrollments.STC_COURSE_NAME + "-" + SectionEnrollments.STC_SECTION_NO
where
    section.SEC_TERM == "2012FL"
orderby section.SEC_SUBJECT,
    section.SEC_COURSE_NO,
    section.SEC_NO
select new {
    section.SEC_SUBJECT,
    section.SEC_COURSE_NO,
    section.SEC_NO,
    SectionEnrollments.SectionEnrollment
};
```

Comment: After a quick glance, does sectionEnrollmentCount.Count() work in the last anonymous object work?

Comment: How fast is your sql query? If it's slow the problem lies within db. Joining on concatenated strings sounds not too good for me.

Comment: Thanks, adding .Count() got the second query to work.  Unfortunately, it took about 20 seconds.  Which is still rather unnacceptable.  The SQL statement takes under a second to execute.

Comment: Run that query with SQL Profiler in the background. This gives you a clue about the number of queries executed and the time each query takes. If there are many queries executed, than there's your problem. If there's one query, run that query through the Index Tuning Wizard. That will give you some clues about any possible missing indexes.

Comment: Try separating your query into a few queries.  You'll probably find that one is returning an IEnumerable rather than an IQueryable.  Your performance is probably suffering because you're probably running a lot of database queries when you iterate through the IEnumerable.

Comment: Do you know how to extract sql predicate that is actually generated from your linq2sql query? Take a look here http://goo.gl/Xv7eN. After you check actual sql you'd get better understanding of what's going on

Comment: I can't really change indexes on the database.  It's a third party database.  The problem is the SQL linq-to-sql is generating.  My guess is I'm not writing the SQL in a way that linq-to-sql will generate an efficient query. What it's generating currently is kinda' ugly.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster You can't directly change the generated sql, so first try to have a look at it. And then try to rewrite your linq-query. It's hard to say what's wrong at the moment as soon as you've provided no info about db itself.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster Now try to profile generated sql-query.

Comment: I've copied the generated SQL into my original question.  I'm new to linq-to-sql so I'm not really sure what to make of it.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster Are you familiar with sql-profiling?

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out this profiler now.

Comment: It just seems to list what has been run.  The execution plans option shows a breakdown of what was done.  36% for index spool and 90% for clustered index scan.  Also, realized the linq-to-sql that I added .Count() to is giving the wrong results.  It's given 1 or 0 for the count.  So I changed the generated SQL in my question to what's from the first attempt since it's given the correct results.

Comment: Maybe [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  Linqer generated a query that returns the results in less then a second.  It's fairly similar to my second attempt.  I'll just have to study it some to try to understand why it works faster.